# Use JavaScript to create table based on array

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to create a table on an HTML page based on an array that I have. The array is populated with items when people click on a button. I have the second bit working but I'm struggling to generate the table based on the populated array. Though I do think that I know why.

I've tried what's in the code block below. It doesn't seem to work. My naive first thought is that it's because there's nothing in the array until it is populated by somebody adding something to their cart. And so the function to create the table doesn't wait, and runs, and therefore returns an error.

```js
function tableGenerator() {
  var cartTable = document.getElementById("cart-table");
  var tbody = document.createElement("tbody");
  cartTable.appendChild(tbody);
  cartItems.forEach(function(items) {
    var row = document.createElement("tr");
    items.forEach(function(item) {
      var cell = document.createElement("td");
      cell.textContent = item;
      row.appendChild(cell);
    });
    tbody.appendChild(row);
  });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Weyland's | Cart</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Weyland's</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

    <div id="navbarNavDropdown" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="shop.html">Shop</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="shipping.html">Shipping</a></li>
      </ul>

      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="login.html">Login</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="register.html">Register</a></li>
        <li>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <span class="navbar-text d-none d-sm-block"> | </span>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="cart.html">Cart</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <table id="cart-table"></table>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="shopScripting.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I'm leaving the rest of the JavaScript and HTML out because it already works and I don't want to complicate the issue. The expected outcome is that a table is generated on the cart page based on the populated array called cartItems.

I'm currently getting the error: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null at tableGenerator.

Comment: What do the contents of `cartItems` look like? Are they each objects?

Comment: Where are you calling `tableGenerator()` in your HTML? Adding event listener?

Comment: Also might be unrelated, you should be using `createTextNode()` on the document nodes to append text values. `textContent` behaviour is for all descendants as well. [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createTextNode)

Comment: @GenericUser [This](https://i.imgur.com/QMAh8Mw.png) image includes the data that gets pushed to the array when a user clicks to add a product to their 'cart'.

Comment: @NathanFries I assumed that it was happening 'on load'. That's part of my problem, really. I'm not sure when it should be called or, rather, how I should be calling it. Because it basically has to be 'listening' constantly. I guess I could call it when the button is clicked to add a product to the cart.

Comment: Thanks @ambianBeing I'll definitely look in to doing that instead.